# Update the global variable after document is ready and use this variable to change HTML with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I have very basic code but i dont know what I am doing wrong here. I am also kinda new in programming and trying to improve myself with exercises.

First I created empty string city variable and I update it with the city information received from API. After variable is updated I want to use that variable as an input in another API to get the weather of that city.

However I am trying to see if variable is actually updated after location API but couldnt manage it? Can you guys help me on that

```js
var city = "";

$.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
    city = $("#city").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
}, "jsonp");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trial").html(city);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {

    font-size: 66px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#city {
    font-size: 33px;
}

#trial {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">
            Weather App
        </h1>
        <div id="city"></div>
        <h1 id="trial">yy</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` returns a `jQuery` object, so your city variable will be a jquery object, and not the string you were expecting. If you assign the response values to the variable then it will get set.

```
let city = ''

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
        city = response.city + ", " + response.region;
        $("#city").html(city);
        console.log(city);
        $("#trial").html(city);
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

What you are doing is running your ajax, which may or may not complete before `.ready()` is fired. you need to wait until the ajax is complete and the callback has been run before you can test for city.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. This is solved my problem.